# jQuery plugin quickPager Next/Prev Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

A site I'm working on is using a jQuery pagination plugin and I need to add a next/prev button, currently it only shows the page numbers and doesn't support next and previous buttons. Below is the code for the plugin, I'm not sure how to go about adding this functionality in.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.quickPager = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        pageSize: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        holder: null,
        pagerLocation: "after"
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);


    return this.each(function() {


        var selector = $(this); 
        var pageCounter = 1;
        var x = 0;

        if( selector.parent("div.simplePagerContainer").length == 0 ) {
            selector.wrap("<div class='simplePagerContainer'></div>");
        }

        selector.parents(".simplePagerContainer").find("ul.simplePagerNav").remove();

        selector.children().each(function(i){ 
            $(this)[0].className = $(this)[0].className.replace(/\bsimplePagerPage.*?\b/g, '');
            if(!$(this).is(":hidden")) {
                if(x < pageCounter*options.pageSize && x >= (pageCounter-1)*options.pageSize) {
                    $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage"+pageCounter);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage"+(pageCounter+1));
                    pageCounter ++;
                }   
                x++;
            }
        });

        // show/hide the appropriate regions 
        selector.children().hide();
        selector.children(".simplePagerPage"+options.currentPage).show();

        if(pageCounter <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        //Build pager navigation
        var pageNav = "<ul class='simplePagerNav'>";

        for (i=1;i<=pageCounter;i++){
            if (i==0) {

            }
            if (i==options.currentPage) {
                pageNav += "<li class='currentPage simplePageNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>"; 
            }
            else {
                pageNav += "<li class='simplePageNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>";
            }
        }
        pageNav += "</ul>";

        if(!options.holder) {
            switch(options.pagerLocation)
            {
            case "before":
                selector.before(pageNav);
            break;
            case "both":
                selector.before(pageNav);
                selector.after(pageNav);
            break;
            default:
                selector.after(pageNav);
            }
        }
        else {
            $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
        }

        //pager navigation behaviour
        selector.parent().find(".simplePagerNav a").click(function() {

            //grab the REL attribute 
            var clickedLink = $(this).attr("rel");
            options.currentPage = clickedLink;

            if(options.holder) {
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("li.currentPage").removeClass("currentPage");
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("currentPage");
            }
            else {
                //remove current current (!) page
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".simplePagerContainer").find("li.currentPage").removeClass("currentPage");
                //Add current page highlighting
                $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".simplePagerContainer").find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("currentPage");
            }

            //hide and show relevant links
            selector.children().hide();         
            selector.find(".simplePagerPage"+clickedLink).show();

            return false;
        });
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nextLink = '<li><a id="nextLink" href="#">Next</a></li>';
var prevLink = '<li><a id="prevLink" href="#">Prev</a></li>';
$(".simplePagerNav").prepend(prevLink).append(nextLink);
$("#nextLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li.currentPage").next("li[class^=simplePageNav]").find("a").click();
});
$("#prevLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li.currentPage").prev("li[class^=simplePageNav]").find("a").click();
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/GCJ5H/)

Comment: How can I use it like :   prev 1 2 ... 10 next   insted of    prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 next